# The review button shows for those of us with less than 2K reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-bar

The review button shows for me, and I suppose for others that don't have 2,000 reputation points, even when the section is supposed to only show for those that do have more than 2,000 reputation points.

Message shown on click:

> You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits.

Comment: Since the documentation review queue has been in existence, users with 100 reputation on Stack Overflow has access to review queues.